# Getting ValidateAntiForgeryToken working with Angular 4 and Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, antiforgerytoken

I am currently attempting to get security working properly with Angular 4 (4.3.5) on the newly released Asp.Net Core 2.0, and specifically anti forgery tokens.

I am using JavascriptServices, which provides the starter application (its the default Angular template in Visual Studio 2017.3). Javascript services hosts the main page of the Angular site on a .cshtml page. This actually turns out to be quite beneficial, as I can then lock everything down using standard forms authentication (dot net core Identity), which redirects the user to a separate (non Angular) login page at /Account/Login when the user is not logged in. You can then log in on that page and get redirected to the home page and the spa is up and running within the context of the authorised user.

That working application may be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/tonywr7/genericangularwebapp).

The final piece of the puzzle is the get the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attributes working. This is fine when you log in to the Account/Login page, as it is not running in the context of angular 4. But when I am running within Angular 4 on the home page, when I make a post back to the server, the post will be blocked by the ValidateAntiForgeryToken if that attribute is present.

Because of this I have commented out the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute on the Account/Logout method. This is because I am logging out from the site using an Angular http post. It works when the attribute is not being used, but it fails/is blocked when it is used.

Following the Angular 4 documention, found [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection), I have changed the Anti Forgery Token name to match what Angular 4 recognises. To do this, I modified my Startup.cs file, adding in some lines, as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            });
...
}
```

This should enable the Angular app to access the Anti Forgery cookie with the name Angular 4 expects.

Within my app, I have just changed over to use the new HttpClient service (apparently the Http service has been deprecated!) which is supposed to use an interceptor to send the XSRF_TOKEN automatically to the server.

But I have been unable to make this work.

I tried a standard post call using the HttpClient service:

```
this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'Account/Logout', "", options).subscribe(result => {
    location.replace("/");
}, error => {
    console.error(error);
})
```

I tried adding headers manually:

```
let token = this.cookieService.get("XSRF-TOKEN");
console.log(token);

var httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'XSRF-TOKEN': token })

this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'Account/Logout', "", { headers: httpHeaders }).subscribe(result => {
    location.replace("/");
}, error => {
    console.error(error);
})
```

I tried using the old service both with and without added headers:

```
let token = this.cookieService.get("XSRF-TOKEN");
        console.log(token);

        let headers = new Headers({
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'Account/Logout', "", options).subscribe(result => {
            location.replace("/")
        }, error => console.error(error));
```

Unfortunately, I've had no luck. Has anyone else managed to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've figured out a solution.

My Index.cshtml page now looks like this:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<app>Loading...</app>

<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

What this does is generate an anti-forgery token on the server side, and place it in a hidden input field on the page. When you view page source, that hidden input field looks like this:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8DaEnvKVNL9EhPVzHKQWhC-PeT4eNm_svdTEyGZje4WnH34sBfG_D_AphtPzBM1JEkQUHsSX1KWBivxAOtPsOvfMKs5N_dLn0Sr3xRG-N2s0oFaa3-yvG87qdzXYm1yBSYH7dlRiBu5It3wi2iYzWqyo4B1i_iRtmikz41gmuldze8VE72zVqmeHZav5rQiHkw" />
```

In my Logout method, I obtain the token and submit it in the headers to the server-side controller. The name of the header is RequestVerificationToken, no underscores necessary.

```
Logout() {

    let token: any = $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();
    if (token !== null) {
        var httpHeaders: any = new HttpHeaders({ 'RequestVerificationToken': token });

        this.httpClient.post("/Account/Logout", null, { headers: httpHeaders }).subscribe(() => {
            window.location.replace("/Account/Login");
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

On the server-side, the AntiForgery filter runs, compares it to the submitted value, and if it is the value expected, will allow the server side Account/Logout method to be executed.

The server-side method looks like this:

```
//
// POST: /Account/Logout
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
  await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
  return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

Putting a break point in the Logout method will prove that it executes.

There might be a gotcha here. I am not sure whether the token changes on each request. I haven't done any testing on this. If it does, then a new token will need to be added to the page after each request.

Also, I did not need to modify the behaviour of the default cookie. I am not doing this the Angular 4 way. It is purely the ASP.Net approach. That is, in the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs file, I have commented out the Cookie changes:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            //{
            //    options.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";
            //    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            //});
```

If you think you've found a better way of doing this, by all means, please post your solution.

Comment: Thank you. I used your technique to get this (mostly) working under Vue.js. I did have to make one modification to make it work. The modification is required because appending headers changed the key to lowercase and it seems the token validation uses case sensitive keys even though header keys are supposed to be case insensitive. In Startup.cs under ConfigureServices I had to add services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "requestverificationtoken");

Comment: I am having a problem, however, that I haven't yet solved. The antiforgery token (or maybe the cookie) has the username/email embedded in it. That means where a user logs in asynchronously the expected token on the server appears to change but of course the token in the page does not. From what I can tell everything is ok as long as the user's login status does not change. For instance, I can open my page and perform actions that are validated. I can logout without refreshing the page and those actions will now fail validation. Likewise if I start logged out and login without a page refresh.

Comment: you used @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in your asp.net view consider that there is an angular 4 app which is not part of MVC routing and view so if you could not have that one what is the alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem here. My solution:

- Adding a Func to the request pipeline like that (F#):

  ```
  member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IHostingEnvironment, appLifetime : IApplicationLifetime, antiforgery : IAntiforgery) =
  let tokenMiddleware = fun (context : HttpContext) (next: Func<Task>) ->
                            let path = context.Request.Path.Value
                            if path <> null && not (path.ToLower().Contains("/api")) then
                                let tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context)
                                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", 
                                    tokens.RequestToken, CookieOptions (
                                                             HttpOnly = false, 
                                                             Secure = false
                                                         )
                                )
                            next.Invoke ()
  app
      .UseStaticFiles()
      .UseIdentityServer()
      .Use(tokenMiddleware)
  ```

The point here is to set secure to false, otherwise the script code won't be able to fetch the cookie.

- In Angular I had to set the header options manually

  ```
  login(login: UserLogin, completed: () => void, failed: (message: string) => void) {
  const token = this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
  const httpHeaders = (token) ? new HttpHeaders({ 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token }) : null;

  this.http.post(this.apiUrl() + AccountServiceService.Login_Url, login, { headers: httpHeaders })
  ```

Works ok for me.
HIH

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` with `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]`

.NET Core 2 changed the process.

https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/Internal/DefaultAntiforgeryTokenGenerator.cs

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to [HttpClient HttpXsrfInterceptor does not set xsrf token for absolute urls](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18859) and [HttpClient does not set X-XSRF-Token on Http Post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20511).

I would suggest if you are able to work with relative url, you can try the following without the `this.baseUrl`:

```
this.httpClient.post('Account/Logout', "", options).subscribe(result => {
    location.replace("/");
}, error => {
    console.error(error);
})
```

You also need to add the following to your startup.cs file to pass XSRF-TOKEN as Set-Cookie:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
...
app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            if (
                string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // We can send the request token as a JavaScript-readable cookie, and Angular will use it by default.
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
                    new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
            }

            return next(context);
        });
...
```

Alternatively, you can try writing your own XSRFInterceptor. A sample is shown [here.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18859#issuecomment-343386182)